# Why does the name of a ocean and river come first (Pacific Ocean, Mississippi River), but for lakes it comes second (Lake Michigan)?

Tags: grammar, word-order, history, semantics, phrase-order

In every example but lakes that I can think of — oceans, rivers, etc. — the name comes first. (An exception is counties in Ireland, e.g. County Cork.)

This makes sense — in English, we say "red shirt," not "shirt red."

Why are lakes different?

Comment: Then there’s the River Nile. Names are tricky things that depend a lot on local custom.

Comment: We say 'River Trent' etc. in the UK.

Comment: You should ask the people who live near Kentucky Lake.

Comment: There is Mount Everest but Table Mountain.

Comment: It's not nearly as clear cut as you think. There are so many exceptions I wouldn't even consider this a general rule. Often, you need to add river, lake, etc to disambiguate. Mississippi might be a football team or a tribe or a state. Good luck with the town of Green River.

Comment: In UK we have Blackwater River and Carew River. We also have River Ouse and River Severn.

Comment: I will point out, in Utah, Great Salt Lake and the city it gives its name to, Salt Lake City.

Comment: @WeatherVane Where in Britain do you have "Blackwater River"? I live close to the "River Blackwater" which forms part of the border between Hampshire and Berkshire. In Britain, by default, *river, lake and mount* go in front of the name.

Comment: @WS2 in Norfolk, the Blackwater River is a tributary of the River Yare. In Dorset, another Blackwater River is a tributary of the River Axe. In Hampshire, another Blackwater River is a tributary of the River Loddon (I think). They are shown that way on the OS maps. I don't know about 'default'. In UK there are a *lot* of rivers with 'River' last. New Bedford River is another.

Comment: @WeatherVane Wow! You are right. I have checked the Ordnance Survey and the Hampshire one which locals would call either "the River Blackwater" or simply "the Blackwater" is shown as the "Blackwater River". It is a tributary of the River Loddon, in turn a tributary of the R.Thames. I'm not at all sure why the OS have done this, perhaps there is some protocol about the river's size. If I find out I will let you know.

Comment: @WS2 generally, it seems to be (many) smaller rivers which are named like that. Similarly with brooks. I can't find a single instance of 'Brook Xxx' as opposed to, say, Tenpenny Brook.

Comment: @WS2 OS maps are [online](https://www.streetmap.co.uk/map.srf?x=601500&y=304500&z=120&sv=Blackwater+River&st=3&tl=Map+of+Blackwater+River,+Norfolk+[Water+Feature]&searchp=ids.srf&mapp=map.srf) under licence.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes. I have an on-line subscription. I'd forgotten that.

Comment: This one is free access.

Comment: Candlewood Lake in Connecticut is another exception. All the names cited seem to have been determined locally, and perhaps arbitrarily.